Runtime Error: The size of tensor a (524288) must match the size of tensor b (131072) at non-singleton dimension 0
I'm trying to perform leaf disease image segmentation using Github code. Here is the code, i am facing this issue "The size of tensor a (524288) must match the size of tensor b (131072) at non-singleton dimension 0". Help me to fix this error. I am unable to understand where the error lies actually.
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.optim import Adam
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from torchvision import transforms
from tqdm import tqdm
import cv2
import os

# Dice coefficient and IoU calculation
def dice_coeff(pred, target):
    smooth = 1.
    pred_flat = pred.view(-1)
    target_flat = target.view(-1)
    intersection = (pred_flat * target_flat).sum()
    return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (pred_flat.sum() + target_flat.sum() + smooth)

def iu_acc(y_pred, y_true):
    smooth = 1e-12
    y_pred_pos = torch.round(torch.clamp(y_pred, 0, 1))
    intersection = torch.sum(y_true * y_pred_pos)
    sum_ = torch.sum(y_true) + torch.sum(y_pred_pos)
    jac = (intersection + smooth) / (sum_ - intersection + smooth)
    return torch.mean(jac)

# Loss function
def dice_coef_loss(pred, target):
    return 1 - dice_coeff(pred, target)

# Define your U-Net model
class ConvBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
        super(ConvBlock, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(out_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(x)))
        return self.relu(self.bn2(self.conv2(x)))

class UpConvBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
        super(UpConvBlock, self).__init__()
        self.up = nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.conv_block = ConvBlock(out_channels * 2, out_channels)

    def forward(self, x1, x2):
        up = self.up(x1)
        return self.conv_block(torch.cat([up, x2], dim=1))

class Unet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels=3, num_classes=1):
        super(Unet, self).__init__()
        self.enc1 = ConvBlock(in_channels, 16)
        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.enc2 = ConvBlock(16, 32)
        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.enc3 = ConvBlock(32, 64)
        self.pool3 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.enc4 = ConvBlock(64, 128)
        self.pool4 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.enc5 = ConvBlock(128, 256)

        self.dec6 = UpConvBlock(256, 128)
        self.dec7 = UpConvBlock(128, 64)
        self.dec8 = UpConvBlock(64, 32)
        self.dec9 = UpConvBlock(32, 16)
        self.out = nn.Conv2d(16, num_classes, kernel_size=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x1 = self.enc1(x)
        x2 = self.pool1(x1)
        x3 = self.enc2(x2)
        x4 = self.pool2(x3)
        x5 = self.enc3(x4)
        x6 = self.pool3(x5)
        x7 = self.enc4(x6)
        x8 = self.pool4(x7)
        x9 = self.enc5(x8)
        y1 = self.dec6(x9, x7)
        y2 = self.dec7(y1, x5)
        y3 = self.dec8(y2, x3)
        y4 = self.dec9(y3, x1)
        out = self.out(y4)
        return out

# Define your dataset class
class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, image_paths, mask_paths, transform=None):
        self.image_paths = image_paths
        self.mask_paths = mask_paths
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.image_paths)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        image_path = self.image_paths[index]
        mask_path = self.mask_paths[index]

        image = cv2.imread(image_path)
        mask = cv2.imread(mask_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
            mask = self.transform(mask)

        image = image.float() / 255.0

        return image, mask

# Define your training and evaluation functions
def train(model, train_loader, optimizer, loss_fn, device):
    model.train()
    epoch_loss = 0.0
    for images, targets in tqdm(train_loader, desc='Training', leave=False):
        images, targets = images.to(device), targets.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(images)
        loss = loss_fn(outputs, targets)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        epoch_loss += loss.item()
    return epoch_loss / len(train_loader)

def evaluate(model, val_loader, loss_fn, device):
    model.eval()
    epoch_loss = 0.0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for images, targets in tqdm(val_loader, desc='Validation', leave=False):
            images, targets = images.to(device), targets.to(device)
            outputs = model(images)
            loss = loss_fn(outputs, targets)
            epoch_loss += loss.item()
    return epoch_loss / len(val_loader)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Define dataset paths
    train_image_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/brown/train/images'
    train_mask_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/brown/train/labels'
    val_image_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/brown/val/images'
    val_mask_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/brown/val/labels'

    # Get image and mask paths
    train_image_paths = sorted([os.path.join(train_image_dir, f) for f in os.listdir(train_image_dir) if f.endswith('.png') or f.endswith('.jpg')])
    train_mask_paths = sorted([os.path.join(train_mask_dir, f) for f in os.listdir(train_mask_dir) if f.endswith('.png') or f.endswith('.jpg')])
    val_image_paths = sorted([os.path.join(val_image_dir, f) for f in os.listdir(val_image_dir) if f.endswith('.png') or f.endswith('.jpg')])
    val_mask_paths = sorted([os.path.join(val_mask_dir, f) for f in os.listdir(val_mask_dir) if f.endswith('.png') or f.endswith('.jpg')])

    # Create datasets
    train_dataset = CustomDataset(train_image_paths, train_mask_paths, transform=transforms.ToTensor())
    val_dataset = CustomDataset(val_image_paths, val_mask_paths, transform=transforms.ToTensor())

    # Define data loaders
    batch_size = 2
    train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
    val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

# Define device, model, optimizer, loss function...
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model = Unet(in_channels=3, num_classes=1)  # Specify the number of input channels and output classes
model = model.to(device)
optimizer = Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-4)

loss_fn = dice_coef_loss  # or your custom loss function

num_epochs = 10
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    train_loss = train(model, train_loader, optimizer, loss_fn, device)
    val_loss = evaluate(model, val_loader, loss_fn, device)
    print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}, Train Loss: {train_loss:.4f}, Val Loss: {val_loss:.4f}')


I tried to another code from Github and got same error. From what i understand it's the issue with my input dimensions. But i am unable to solve it.
Image file: dimension: 256 by 256 , bit depth: 24, extension: .jpg
Mask file: dimension: 256 by 256 , bit depth: 8, extension: .png
Update: Here is my complete error
    --> 178 train_loss = train(model, train_loader, optimizer, loss_fn, device)
    179     val_loss = evaluate(model, val_loader, loss_fn, device)
    180     print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}, Train Loss: {train_loss:.4f}, Val Loss: {val_loss:.4f}')

train(model, train_loader, optimizer, loss_fn, device)
    127         optimizer.zero_grad()
    128         outputs = model(images)
--> 129         loss = loss_fn(outputs, targets)
    130         loss.backward()
    131         optimizer.step()

dice_coef_loss(pred, target)
     32 # Loss function
     33 def dice_coef_loss(pred, target):
---> 34     return 1 - dice_coeff(pred, target)
# Define your U-Net model
dice_coeff(pred, target)
     16     pred_flat = pred.view(-1)
     17     target_flat = target.view(-1)
---> 18     intersection = (pred_flat * target_flat).sum()
     19     return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (pred_flat.sum() + target_flat.sum() + smooth)

RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (524288) must match the size of tensor b (131072) at non-singleton dimension 0

Can you try zip(trainloader) in train function at the for loop?

Still same error

I just resized the prediction output to match the spatial resolution of target in dice_coeff method and it solved the problem:
    # Dice coefficient and IoU calculation
def dice_coeff(pred, target):
    smooth = 1.
    # Resize pred to match the spatial resolution of target
    pred_resized = F.interpolate(pred, size=target.shape[-2:], mode='bilinear', align_corners=True)
    # Print shapes for debugging
    #print("Resized Pred shape:", pred_resized.shape)
    #print("Target shape:", target.shape)
    pred_flat = pred_resized.view(pred_resized.size(0), -1)
    target_flat = target.view(target.size(0), -1)
    intersection = (pred_flat * target_flat).sum(dim=1)
    return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (pred_flat.sum(dim=1) + target_flat.sum(dim=1) + smooth)

def iu_acc(y_pred, y_true):
    smooth = 1e-12
    y_pred_pos = torch.round(torch.clamp(y_pred, 0, 1))
    y_pred_pos_resized = F.interpolate(y_pred_pos, size=y_true.shape[-2:], mode='nearest')  # Resize predicted tensor
    intersection = torch.sum(y_true * y_pred_pos_resized)
    sum_ = torch.sum(y_true) + torch.sum(y_pred_pos_resized)
    jac = (intersection + smooth) / (sum_ - intersection + smooth)
    return torch.mean(jac)

# Loss function
def dice_coef_loss(pred, target):
    return 1.0 - dice_coeff(pred, target).mean()

# Define your U-Net model
class ConvBlock(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
        super(ConvBlock, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(out_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(x)))
        return self.relu(self.bn2(self.conv2(x)))

class UpConvBlock(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
        super(UpConvBlock, self).__init__()
        self.up = nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.conv_block = ConvBlock(out_channels * 2, out_channels)

    def forward(self, x1, x2):
        up = self.up(x1)
        return self.conv_block(torch.cat([up, x2], dim=1))

class Unet(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, in_channels=3, num_classes=1):
        super(Unet, self).__init__()
        self.enc1 = ConvBlock(in_channels, 16)
        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.enc2 = ConvBlock(16, 32)
        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.enc3 = ConvBlock(32, 64)
        self.pool3 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.enc4 = ConvBlock(64, 128)
        self.pool4 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.enc5 = ConvBlock(128, 256)

        self.dec6 = UpConvBlock(256, 128)
        self.dec7 = UpConvBlock(128, 64)
        self.dec8 = UpConvBlock(64, 32)
        self.dec9 = UpConvBlock(32, 16)
        self.out = nn.Conv2d(16, num_classes, kernel_size=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x1 = self.enc1(x)
        x2 = self.pool1(x1)
        x3 = self.enc2(x2)
        x4 = self.pool2(x3)
        x5 = self.enc3(x4)
        x6 = self.pool3(x5)
        x7 = self.enc4(x6)
        x8 = self.pool4(x7)
        x9 = self.enc5(x8)
        y1 = self.dec6(x9, x7)
        y2 = self.dec7(y1, x5)
        y3 = self.dec8(y2, x3)
        y4 = self.dec9(y3, x1)
        out = self.out(y4)
        return out

# Define your dataset class
class CustomDataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, image_paths, mask_paths, transform=None):
        self.image_paths = image_paths
        self.mask_paths = mask_paths
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.image_paths)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        image_path = self.image_paths[index]
        mask_path = self.mask_paths[index]

        image = cv2.imread(image_path)
        mask = cv2.imread(mask_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
            mask = self.transform(mask)

        image = image.float() / 255.0

        return image, mask

def train(model, train_loader, optimizer, loss_fn, device):
    model.train()
    epoch_loss = 0.0
    epoch_dc = 0.0
    epoch_iou = 0.0
    num_batches = len(train_loader)
    for images, targets in tqdm(train_loader, desc='Training', leave=False):
        images, targets = images.to(device), targets.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(images)
        loss = loss_fn(outputs, targets)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        epoch_loss += loss.item()
        with torch.no_grad():
            pred_masks = torch.sigmoid(outputs)
            dc = dice_coeff(pred_masks, targets)
            iou = iu_acc(pred_masks, targets)
            epoch_dc += dc.mean().item()  # Compute mean and then get item
            epoch_iou += iou.mean().item()  # Compute mean and then get item
    return epoch_loss / num_batches, epoch_dc / num_batches, epoch_iou / num_batches

def evaluate(model, val_loader, loss_fn, device):
    model.eval()
    epoch_loss = 0.0
    epoch_dc = 0.0
    epoch_iou = 0.0
    num_batches = len(val_loader)
    with torch.no_grad():
        for images, targets in tqdm(val_loader, desc='Validation', leave=False):
            images, targets = images.to(device), targets.to(device)
            outputs = model(images)
            loss = loss_fn(outputs, targets)
            epoch_loss += loss.item()
            pred_masks = torch.sigmoid(outputs)
            dc = dice_coeff(pred_masks, targets)
            iou = iu_acc(pred_masks, targets)
            epoch_dc += dc.mean().item()  # Compute mean and then accumulate
            epoch_iou += iou.mean().item()  # Compute mean and then accumulate
    return epoch_loss / num_batches, epoch_dc / num_batches, epoch_iou / num_batches

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Define dataset paths
    train_image_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/brown/train/images'
    train_mask_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/brown/train/labels'
    val_image_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/brown/val/images'
    val_mask_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/brown/val/labels'

    # Get image and mask paths
    train_image_paths = sorted([os.path.join(train_image_dir, f) for f in os.listdir(train_image_dir) if f.endswith('.png') or f.endswith('.jpg')])
    train_mask_paths = sorted([os.path.join(train_mask_dir, f) for f in os.listdir(train_mask_dir) if f.endswith('.png') or f.endswith('.jpg')])
    val_image_paths = sorted([os.path.join(val_image_dir, f) for f in os.listdir(val_image_dir) if f.endswith('.png') or f.endswith('.jpg')])
    val_mask_paths = sorted([os.path.join(val_mask_dir, f) for f in os.listdir(val_mask_dir) if f.endswith('.png') or f.endswith('.jpg')])

    # Create datasets
    train_dataset = CustomDataset(train_image_paths, train_mask_paths, transform=transforms.ToTensor())
    val_dataset = CustomDataset(val_image_paths, val_mask_paths, transform=transforms.ToTensor())

    # Define data loaders
    batch_size = 2
    train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
    val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

# Define device, model, optimizer, loss function...
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model = Unet(in_channels=3, num_classes=1)  # Specify the number of input channels and output classes
model = model.to(device)
optimizer = Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-4)

loss_fn = dice_coef_loss  # or your custom loss function

# Initialize lists to store metrics
epochs = []
train_losses = []
val_losses = []
train_dice_coefficients = []
val_dice_coefficients = []
train_iou_scores = []
val_iou_scores = []

num_epochs = 10
# Training loop with image plotting
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    train_loss, train_dc, train_iou = train(model, train_loader, optimizer, loss_fn, device)
    val_loss, val_dc, val_iou = evaluate(model, val_loader, loss_fn, device)

    # Append metrics to lists
    epochs.append(epoch + 1)
    train_losses.append(train_loss)
    val_losses.append(val_loss)
    train_dice_coefficients.append(train_dc)
    train_iou_scores.append(train_iou)
    val_dice_coefficients.append(val_dc)
    val_iou_scores.append(val_iou)

table = {
    "Epoch": epochs,
    "Train Loss": train_losses,
    "Val Loss": val_losses,
    "Train Dice Coefficient": train_dice_coefficients,
    "Train IoU": train_iou_scores,
    "Val Dice Coefficient": val_dice_coefficients,
    "Val IoU": val_iou_scores
}

# Print the table
print(tabulate(table, headers="keys", tablefmt="grid"))

